# Doctrine flush remove existing entity values

Tags: php, doctrine, fosoauthserverbundle

My entity is:

```
namespace OAuthBundle\Entity;

use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\Client as BaseClient;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table("oauth_client")
 */
class Client extends BaseClient
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param $name
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

In FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Model that extends FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\Client there are some field and one of them is randomId

When i try insert some record with doctrine like:

```
    $client = new Client();
    $client->setId(4);
    $client->setRandomId('1wy8z9ayt6kgsw0s4cwk04ogs884cg08kkgg04gso4kckcscog');
    $client->setRedirectUris(array('http://foo.com'));
    $client->setSecret('59az3u43xn4so4g4wswscso4kookwsw00488oogw8kw4w4wgg0');
    $client->setAllowedGrantTypes(array('token', 'authorization_code','http://bar.com/grants/foo' ,'refresh_token'));
    $client->setName('foobarApp');

    $manager->persist($client);
    $manager->flush();
```

I receive from doctrine the error:

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\NotNullConstraintViolationException: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO oauth_client (name) VALUES (?)' with params ["TestClient"]:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'random_id' doesn't have a default value
```

The dump of $client->getRandomId() just before the flush returns the correct value.

If I persist and flush an existing entity retrived from the database and updated it works normally.

Does anyone knows why doctrine ignore some of the value of the entity when builds the insert query?

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `oauth_client` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `random_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `redirect_uris` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)',
  `secret` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `allowed_grant_types` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)',
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The BaseClient class is:

```
class Client implements ClientInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $randomId;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $secret;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $redirectUris = array();

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $allowedGrantTypes = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->allowedGrantTypes[] = OAuth2::GRANT_TYPE_AUTH_CODE;

        $this->setRandomId(Random::generateToken());
        $this->setSecret(Random::generateToken());
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setRandomId($random)
    {
        $this->randomId = $random;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getRandomId()
    {
        return $this->randomId;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getPublicId()
    {
        return sprintf('%s_%s', $this->getId(), $this->getRandomId());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setSecret($secret)
    {
        $this->secret = $secret;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSecret()
    {
        return $this->secret;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function checkSecret($secret)
    {
        return null === $this->secret || $secret === $this->secret;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setRedirectUris(array $redirectUris)
    {
        $this->redirectUris = $redirectUris;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getRedirectUris()
    {
        return $this->redirectUris;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setAllowedGrantTypes(array $grantTypes)
    {
        $this->allowedGrantTypes = $grantTypes;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAllowedGrantTypes()
    {
        return $this->allowedGrantTypes;
    }
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52667480/edit) your question and show us the structure of the table `oauth_client` and of the entity `BaseClient` ?

Comment: Have you got a `fos_oauth_server` configuration block? And have you added `FOSOAuthServerBundle` to your Doctrine mappings? It sounds like the parent class isn't being mapped properly - the [Getting Started page](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) explains what you need to do.

Comment: Is random_id  auto incremented, this may cause the proble - the database generating the random id upon the insert. If not, have you tried to put nullable as default value fot the random id ?